# SSIS XML Source Error Output resets to fail component after setting to redirect row

Tags: xml, ssis, dataflowtask

I am using XML Source component to insert data from an xml file to a sql database table.  When the component has an error, it should redirect the row to a script component. I have tried setting the Error Output to redirect rows but each time I set it, click ok and reopen the component, the Error Output changes back to fail component. Is there a setting I am missing?

I have tried setting all of the columns to redirect rows, looked in the properties for a possible setting and even googled but doesn't bring up any hits.